# Does this weak distinguishing relation among sets have a name?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Sets $A$ and $B$ in a topological space are [name?] if and only if there exists a nonempty open set $E$ such that $E\subset A$ and $E\cap B=\emptyset$.

Since $A$ and $B$ need not be disjoint, modifications of the word "separated" seem inappropriate.  Perhaps the condition above is equivalent to some standard relation among sets in a topological space?

Comment: It's equivalent to $A \cap (X-B)$ containing an open set, if that counts as a "standard relation among sets in a topological space." (X is the ambient topological space.)

Comment: Rather: $A\setminus B$ has nonempty interior. Or: $A^\circ\setminus \bar B$ is not empty.

Comment: Thank you.  There probably is no single word used yet.  Just wanted to check first before naming the property myself.